# Magento Display coupon discounts on 2 line instead of 1

Tags: magento

I currently have 2 shopping cart rules each for $5.00. Magento combines them; how do i get Magento to do them seperately

Currently it does:

> Discount (Monthly Promotion, Family Rocks Save 5) -$10.00

What i want it to do:

> Discount (Monthly Promotion -5.00 Family Rocks Save           -5.00

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is not possible without modifying the way magento works by default, are you able to code magento extensions?